# Cannot render the context with OpenGL using EGL

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, egl

I try to display empty red screen with OpenGL using EGL. However, the window looks like a transparent background, nothing is rendered. I posted the code below.

If I comment out the binding (eglBindAPI), the red screen is displayed since the default api (OpenGL ES) is used instead of OpenGL.

I cannot find out the reason why the binding api causes such a problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <EGL/egl.h>
#include <EGL/eglplatform.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

GLint windowHeight = 800;
GLint windowWidth = 600;

bool quit = false;

LRESULT CALLBACK wndProc(HWND hwnd, unsigned int msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch (msg)
  {
  case WM_CLOSE: {
    quit = true;
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
  }
  case WM_SIZE: {
    windowWidth = LOWORD(lParam);
    windowHeight = HIWORD(lParam);
    return 0;
  }
  }

  return (DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam));
}

HWND createWindow(int width, int height) 
{
  HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
  WNDCLASSEX wcex;

  wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
  wcex.style = CS_OWNDC;
  wcex.lpfnWndProc = &DefWindowProc;
  wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
  wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
  wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
  wcex.hIcon = NULL;
  wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  wcex.hbrBackground = 0;
  wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
  wcex.lpszClassName = L"eglsamplewnd";
  wcex.hIconSm = NULL;
  wcex.lpfnWndProc = wndProc;

  RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
  RECT rect = { 0, 0, width, height };
  int style = WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME;
  AdjustWindowRect(&rect, style, FALSE);

  HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(L"eglsamplewnd", L"EGL OpenGL SC", style, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, NULL, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
  ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);

  return hwnd;
}

int main()
{
  HWND hwnd = createWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

  EGLDisplay eglDisplay = eglGetDisplay(hdc);

  if (eglDisplay == EGL_NO_DISPLAY) 
  {
    cout << "Could not get egl display!" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  EGLint eglVersionMajor, eglVersionMinor;
  eglInitialize(eglDisplay, &eglVersionMajor, &eglVersionMinor);

  EGLint configAttributes[] =
  {
    EGL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32,
    EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
    EGL_COLOR_BUFFER_TYPE, EGL_RGB_BUFFER,
    EGL_CONFORMANT, EGL_OPENGL_BIT,
    EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24,
    EGL_LEVEL, 0,
    EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_BIT,
    EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, 0,
    EGL_SAMPLES, 0,
    EGL_STENCIL_SIZE, 0,
    EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
    EGL_TRANSPARENT_TYPE, EGL_NONE,
    EGL_TRANSPARENT_RED_VALUE, EGL_DONT_CARE,
    EGL_TRANSPARENT_GREEN_VALUE, EGL_DONT_CARE,
    EGL_TRANSPARENT_BLUE_VALUE, EGL_DONT_CARE,
    EGL_NONE
  };

  EGLint nrOfConfigs;
  EGLConfig windowConfig;
  EGLBoolean retVal = eglChooseConfig(eglDisplay, configAttributes, &windowConfig, 1, &nrOfConfigs);

  if (retVal == EGL_FALSE)
  {
    cout << "Could not get valid egl configuration!" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  EGLint surfaceAttributes[] = { EGL_NONE };

  EGLSurface eglSurface = eglCreateWindowSurface(eglDisplay, windowConfig, hwnd, surfaceAttributes);

  if (eglSurface == EGL_NO_SURFACE)
  {
    cerr << "Could not create EGL surface : " << eglGetError() << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  eglBindAPI(EGL_OPENGL_API);

  EGLint contextAttributes[] = { EGL_NONE };
  EGLContext eglContext = eglCreateContext(eglDisplay, windowConfig, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, contextAttributes);

  if (eglContext == EGL_NO_CONTEXT) 
  {
    cout << "Could not create egl context : " << eglGetError() << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay, eglSurface, eglSurface, eglContext);

  while (!quit) 
  {
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    eglSwapBuffers(eglDisplay, eglSurface);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0))
    {
      TranslateMessage(&msg);
      DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am using EGL 1.4 and Open GL not OpenGL ES

Comment: What does [`eglQueryString()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglQueryString.xhtml) with `EGL_VENDOR` & `EGL_CLIENT_APIS` return?

Comment: It returns as follows: Version: "1.4" Vendor: "Intel" API: "OpenGL OpenGL_ES OpenGL_ES2" Extensions: "EGL_KHR_create_context" I got your point. Although I have Intel graphics card ( Intel HD Graphics 530) and compatible EGL lib (I guess),it still does not work.

Comment: Time to start checking return values & `eglGetError()` then.  Are `eglBindAPI()` & `eglMakeCurrent()` succeeding?  What are `GL_VERSION`/`GL_RENDERER`/`GL_VENDOR` after the `eglMakeCurrent()` (assuming it succeeds)?

Comment: There is no any errors. I received following values:
GL_RENDERER: "Intel (R) HD Graphics 530", GL_VENDOR: "Intel", GL_VERSION: "4.4.0"